# No component factory found for TasklistItemsFormComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm receiving the error `No component factory found for TasklistItemsFormComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents` but **I have added** the component to my lazy loaded module's `entryComponents` section.

Here's my app.routing:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Início'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
        canActivate: [AdminGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'tasklists',
        loadChildren: './tasklists/tasklists.module#TasklistsModule',
        canActivate: [AdminGuard]
      }
    ]
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: [
    AdminGuard,
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The TasklistModule:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';

import { TasklistsRoutingModule } from './tasklists-routing.module';
import { TasklistsSearchComponent } from './tasklists-search/tasklists-search.component';
import { TasklistsFormComponent } from './tasklists-form/tasklists-form.component';


import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';

import { DateFormatPipe } from '../shared/pipes/date-format.pipe';
import { TasklistResourcesComponent } from './tasklist-resources/tasklist-resources.component';
import { TasklistItemsComponent } from './tasklist-items/tasklist-items.component';
import { TasklistResourcesFormComponent } from './tasklist-resources/tasklist-resources-form/tasklist-resources-form.component';
import { TasklistItemsFormComponent } from './tasklist-items/tasklist-items-form/tasklist-items-form.component';
import { TasklistItemsGridComponent } from './tasklist-items/tasklist-items-grid/tasklist-items-grid.component';
import { TasklistResourcesGridComponent } from './tasklist-resources/tasklist-resources-grid/tasklist-resources-grid.component';
import { TasklistSubformHeaderComponent } from './tasklist-subform-header/tasklist-subform-header.component';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
    NgSelectModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TasklistsRoutingModule,
    BsDatepickerModule,
    MomentModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    TasklistsSearchComponent,
    TasklistsFormComponent,
    DateFormatPipe,
    TasklistResourcesComponent,
    TasklistItemsComponent,
    TasklistResourcesFormComponent,
    TasklistItemsFormComponent,
    TasklistItemsGridComponent,
    TasklistResourcesGridComponent,
    TasklistSubformHeaderComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    TasklistItemsFormComponent,
    TasklistItemsGridComponent]
})
export class TasklistsModule { }
```

I have also the AppModule and the SharedModule (I'm moving some declarations from AppModule to SharedModule from time to time).

Comment: Try adding `TasklistItemsFormComponent` to the `exports` array. Also remember to reload the dev server.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you trying to use the `TasklistItemsFormComponent` outside of `TasklistsModule`?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324

Comment: No. The only place referencing `TasklistItemsFormComponent` is `TasklistItemsGridComponent`, where I use `BsModalRef` to display a Modal pointing to `TasklistItemsFormComponent`.

Comment: `ngx-bootstrap` has a reported issue pointing exactly to the same problem: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2356. I think the current way to workaround this is to move this component away from a lazy loaded module.

Comment: Looks like this is the only solution.

Comment: Tested and working with this workaround. I'll let the question open just in case something new comes up to solve this. Thanks @TomaszKula

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Found a new workaround. Adding `ModalModule.forRoot()` to the list of import of the `TasklistsModule`. Even though I don't know if this can cause any issues (using forRoot in a child module).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169442/discussion-between-tomasz-kula-and-juliano-nunes-silva-oliveira).